# Running multiple versions of Node.js only running latest

Tags: node.js, github-actions

I have followed the guidelines for [Running multiple versions of Node.js](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-running-multiple-versions-of-nodejs) using a [matrix strategy](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstrategymatrix):

`.github/workflows/build-test.yml`:

```yaml
    jobs:
      build_and_test:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
        strategy:
          matrix:
            node: [10, 12, 14]
```

The workflow does initiate to test with the intended three different versions of Node:

[image: GitHub Actions workflow]

However, each is running with the latest:

[image: Workflow expecting Node v14]

For example, for Node v14, the workflow instead used Node v16.14.2:

```
/usr/local/bin/node --version
v16.14.2
/usr/local/bin/npm --version
8.5.0
```

Why is this happening?

Full yaml

```
name: Build and Test

on:
  push:
    branches: [master]
  pull_request:
    branches: [master]

jobs:
  build_and_test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node: [10, 12, 14]

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      - name: Install project
        run: npm install
      - name: Build the project
        run: npm run build --if-present
      - name: Run tests
        run: npm test
```

Comment: Are you actually _using_ the matrix parameters? Give a [mre].

Comment: @jonrsharpe, just uploaded the full yaml, which includes `with: node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}`

Comment: `uses: actions/setup-node@v1` - does that version actually support this functionality? The latest is v3 (and I've definitely [had this working](https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit/runs/6160228911?check_suite_focus=true), [in v2](https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit/blob/7931767d3ecd72292062559e7a4693dd47428464/.github/workflows/push.yml#L39-L42)), why are you using v1?

Comment: It _was_ supported [in v1](https://github.com/actions/setup-node/tree/releases/v1#usage), but you have to actually use the variable you defined, `"node-version" !== "node"`: `node-version: ${{ matrix.node }}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the suggestion from **@jonrsharpe** to use the **latest v3**, this works:

.github/workflows/build-test.yml

```
name: Build and Test

on:
  push:
    branches: [master]
  pull_request:
    branches: [master]

jobs:
  build_and_test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node: [12, 14]

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node }}
          cache: npm
      - name: Install project
        run: npm install
      - name: Build the project
        run: npm run build --if-present
      - name: Run tests
        run: npm test
```

Comment: It wasn't the version at all, it was that `matrix.node-version` didn't refer to any value you'd actually defined. That's why it didn't show in the title either.

Comment: Thank you, most appreciative of your feedback.